# My site load is very high. JS files are slowing it down

Tags: php, apache, load

I have a site that was very slow with load time approx. >15s. I read a lot of articles and optimized it and brought it down to 5-6 sec. But, My JS files loading are a real pain. They are getting blocked and increasing site load time.

Image of the waterfall from GTMetrix.

[image]

Comment: _all_ files beeing downloaded from your domain digitizebrand.com are very slow. At least load bootstrap, lazysizes, etc from a cdn (like you do with jquery). And maybe get a better hoster or hosting plan/deal??

Comment: But loading from CDN would add another time looking for the DNS. That's why I loaded it from my domain instead.

Comment: no, because it's likeley that those scripts are in cache of the user already. And because they have a much better loading time than your server has (just look at the image!)

Comment: Ok. I figured out that you were right. Coz I did load jQuery from CDN and loaded quick. Thanks.